# Prolog: "\+ memberchk" inside "setof"

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

I have some Prolog code of the following form:

```
setof(Element,some_function(P,Element,C),Elements)
```

such that all instantiations of term `Element` in solution to `some_function` are collected in list `Elements`.

I now want to improve this with `memberchk` such that any instantiation of term `Element` is only added to `Elements` if it doesn't exist on a list `List`.

I have tried the following:

```
setof(Element,some_function(P,Element,C,List),Elements)

................

some_function(P,Element,C,List) :-
.... the function as it was ....,
\+ memberchk(Element,List).
```

This does work in the sense that only elements that are not on `List` are added. But the problem is that `setof` now fails when all instantiations of term `Element` are already on `List`. Whereas I would like it to return an empty list `Elements`, but not fail.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Ah brilliant! Yes that is exactly what I am after, thanks. Should I delete my question?

Comment: leave it, your formulation is fine. It might help others to find the answer too